# How to add multiple flat rate shipping

Tags: shipping, magento-1, table-rates, delivery

I am not sure if I need table rates here, but what I need to establish is 3 shipping costs per order, to UK only...

Essentially,

- £2.95 (3-5 days)
- £4.95 (1-3 days)
- Order over £50, free delivery

I have got in the free delivery and a flat rate at £2.95, but **how can I add a second flat rate**? Do I need to do it as a table rate or something?? I am sure this might help many people, with simple shop setups like mine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case where you want to have the customer choose from multiple options, I recommend using one of WebShopApps matrix plugins. Here's a good one:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension-certified-bug-free.html

Otherwise, to get an automatic calculation based on value, use table rates to achieve what you're looking for - to get an example of a table rates CSV:

[image]

For the £50 free delivery option, use free shipping shopping cart price rules.

<sub>Source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping</sub>

Comment: are you able to have multiple conflicting/simultanious options though?

I.E buyer able to choose between 2 types of postage?

Comment: I get a conflict...

`File has not been imported. See the following list of errors: Duplicate Row #3 (Country "GBR", Region/State "*", Zip "*" and Value "0").
Duplicate Row #4 (Country "GBR", Region/State "*", Zip "*" and Value "0").`

Comment: I don't know that you can have a choice - that's a different type of shipping method. Table rates is an automatic calculation either based on weight or price, or both

Comment: In this case, I recommend using one of WebShopApps matrix plugins

Comment: I think Neklo.com solution is much better. See Thebod_Shippingrates

Comment: @philwinkle Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps matrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps matrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps matrix rate.

Comment: Anyone knows how to give free shipping using Webshopapps  Matrix Rates in SHopping Cart Pricing rule?

Comment: try this [multiple flat rate shipping for magento 2](https://www.mageants.com/multi-flat-shipping-extension-for-magento-2.html) with this module you can easily set in your store

Answer (score 8):

You could also create a **second flat rate shipping method with a module**.

First create `app/etc/modules/Vendor_Module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core/>
                <Mage_Catalog/>
            </depends>
        </Vendor_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Then create `app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>

    <modules>
        <Vendor_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Vendor_Module>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <module>
                <class>Vendor_Module_Model</class>
            </module>
        </models>

        <helpers>
            <module>
                <class>Vendor_Module_Helper</class>
            </module>
        </helpers>

    </global>

    <default>
        <flatrate2>
            <active>1</active>
            <sallowspecific>0</sallowspecific>
            <model>module/carrier_flatrate2</model>
            <title>Flat Rate 2</title>
            <type>I</type>
            <specificerrmsg>This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.</specificerrmsg>
            <handling_type>F</handling_type>
        </flatrate2>
    </default>
</config>
```

Add the configuration fields after that in `app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/system.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <carriers>
            <groups>
                <flatrate2 translate="label" module="module">
                    <label>Flat Rate 2</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>21</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                        <name translate="label">
                            <label>Method Name</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </name>
                        <price translate="label">
                            <label>Price</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                            <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </price>
                        <handling_type translate="label">
                            <label>Calculate Handling Fee</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>shipping/source_handlingType</source_model>
                            <sort_order>7</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </handling_type>
                        <handling_fee translate="label">
                            <label>Handling Fee</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <validate>validate-number validate-zero-or-greater</validate>
                            <sort_order>8</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </handling_fee>
                        <sort_order translate="label">
                            <label>Sort Order</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </sort_order>
                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </title>
                        <type translate="label">
                            <label>Type</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_flatrate</source_model>
                            <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </type>
                        <sallowspecific translate="label">
                            <label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                            <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_allspecificcountries</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </sallowspecific>
                        <specificcountry translate="label">
                            <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>91</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                            <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                        </specificcountry>
                        <showmethod translate="label">
                            <label>Show Method if Not Applicable</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>92</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </showmethod>
                        <specificerrmsg translate="label">
                            <label>Displayed Error Message</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>80</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </specificerrmsg>
                    </fields>
                </flatrate2>
            </groups>
        </carriers>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Now you need to create the carrier models, to avoid duplicate code, this model extends the original flatrate carrier and only changes the fields that need to be changed

`app/code/local/Vendor/Module/Model/Carrier/Flatrate2.php`

```
<?php

class Vendor_Module_Model_Carrier_Flatrate2
    extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrate
    implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{

    protected $_code = 'flatrate2';

    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return array('flatrate2'=>$this->getConfigData('name'));
    }

}
```

Finally don't forget to create your helper:

`app/code/local/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php

class Vendor_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Comment: I followed all the steps as outlined above - where can I find the second flat rate shipping method now? Thank you.

Comment: can u provide github link

Comment: Anyone knows how to give free shipping using Webshopapps  Matrix Rates in SHopping Cart Pricing rule?

Answer (score 5):

There is open source extension which allows to setup multiple flat rates:
https://github.com/thebod/Thebod_Shippingrates

[image]