# Which file controls the 3. Shipping Method during checkout?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, calendar

```
Magento 1.9.4
Porto theme
```

I am trying to setup a 2nd flat rate shipping method as per here:

[How to add another flat rate shipping option?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227765/how-to-add-another-flat-rate-shipping-option)

and I'm already having problems with that which I wonder if they have to do with some difference in Magento version 1.9.1 versus 1.9.4?

Anyways, once I get that added on (we use one flat rate shipping price for deliveries in the city and another rate for everything outside our city), I previously setup a calendar from Amasty on the shipping page of the check-out.

Given the 2 scenarios:

1. flat rate for DELIVERIES in the city
2. flat rate for shipping outside the city

The calendar was used for only the local delivery option #1 in our city. Customers were getting confused, however, and they were selecting a date from the calendar for the nationwide delivery (option #2). So someone helped me set it up in such a way that the calendar would appear ONLY when the customer selected option #1. This was in our Magento 1.9.1 version. We just setup with a new install on Magento 1.9.4 and I cannot remember which file had those modifications.

**What file/files could I possibly look for on our old Magento 1.9.1 system that would be responsible for this? (would potentially had that modified code to make the calendar appear/disappear based on which shipping option is selected?)**

I know we spent a lot of time making this modification and my goal is to identify which file has that code and just copy that over from my old Magento 1.9.1 install into the Magento 1.9.4 new installation.

Answer (score 0):

You should check with class `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available` , you can check this class in old magento backup or you can override it and add conditions

Comment: Where would one find this on Magento 1.9.1/1.9.4? Just to clarify - what I'm after is where could we have set the logic of when customer clicks flatrateshipping1-show calendar; if customer clicks shippingmethod 2-hide calendar

Comment: here is the path app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Shipping/Method/Available.php

Comment: you can what you need with this file, you can add conditions here, app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the two codebases using a diff tool to identify the differences.

There are a large number of possibilities.

It's likely that this logic is written in JS, which is added to the checkout page via layout.xml.

Depending on the checkout module you are using, it might be added to the page using the addItem layout instruction.

If you search all xml files for amasty/amdeliverydate/deliverydate.js you might just find the same layout file which is adding the custom javascript.

You can also verify what JS files are loading using the network tab in the google developer tools window.

The custom logic may have also been added to the same JS file...